# Custom auto increment string field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to save a custom auto increment string when someone create an order like this:

```
ID | CUSTOM_ID
1  | product-001
2  | service-001
3  | service-002
4  | product-002
```

What's the best way in ruby on rails to limit queries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/celsodantas/protokoll) a gem called Protokoll, as the description says : `Protokoll is a simple Rails gem to create custom autoincrement values to a database column`, never used it before but at you to see if this is what do you search for. Hope this help you

Comment: Exactly what i searched. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating a slug for searching, try the [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem. It creates such strings and have lots of options for the configuration (for example, when to create or change the slug).

EDIT: The you're looking for `before_create`. Use it like this:

```
before_create :add_custom_id

def add_custom_id
  self.custom_id = "service_#{id}" # whatever you need
end
```

It will run the `add_custom_id` method before creating a new instance in the db.

More info on the ActiveRecord::Callbacks can be found in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

Comment: Not really, it's just to create a specific custom ref for special orders